# How to make two-dimensional array of enum values and integers

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

I need to make two-dimensional array of Students grades.
So I have Subjects

```
public enum Subjects
{
    Programming, Design, Administration
}
```

Despite, I'm trying to get enum values in array I have Exeptions.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Subjects[,] grades = new Subjects[Enum.Parse(typeof(Subjects), 5];
      }
}
```

I need to make array like this [enum.Subjects,integers of grades for every subject]
Is it possible?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to use a 2D array. Instead perhaps a `Dictionary<Subjects, int>` or a `List<StudentGrade>` where `StudentGrade` is a class with 2 properties containing the subject and grade.

Comment: *I need to make two-dimensional array of Students grades* That is a solution, not a requirement. What is the requirement? What do you need to be able to do with your data structure?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a 'gradebook' where you want to keep 5 grades for eacht subject, you could do something like:

```
public enum Subjects
{
    Programming, Design, Administration
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var grades = new Dictionary<Subjects, int[]>();
        foreach (Subjects subject in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Subjects)))
        {
            grades.Add(subject, new int[5]);
        }
        // example of use:
        grades[Subjects.Programming][0] = 0;
    }
}
```

But I agree with the comments stating that we could help you better if you could describe what your problem is rather than how you want to solve it.

Comment: I'd recommend using a `List<int>` rather than `int[]` as it makes it far easier to add new grades and you're not limited to a set number of 5.